# select query after merge not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I am doing the following steps:

- Merge stmt. The merge statement inserts values into view if they are not present.
- Select stmt. To select the records that I inserted

But the select query returns blank. The sample code is given below:

```
declare @now AS DATETIME = GETUTCDATE(),
        @uuid AS INT = 1;

MERGE A.V_Table AS T
(
  Select 
     A1,
     A2
  FROM B.Table
)S
on T.A1 = T1.A1
   and T.A2 = T1.A2
when not matched by target then
insert
(
  A1,
  A2,
  UpdateUUID,
  UpdateTimeStamp
)
values
(
 s.a1,
 s.a2,
 @uuid,
@now
);

select *
from A.V_Table
where updateuUid = @uuid and UpdateTimeStamp = @now;
```

If I print out the values of @now and @uuid and use those values in the select query, the records are returned. But not when its executed as above.

Does any idea why this should be so? Isn't the select query run only after the merge is completed?

Comment: is uuid instead of the variable name a typo? and have you proved that something should be inserted?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thanks. its a typo.
Yes, I checked that something would be inserted.
I printed out "@now, @uuid" and ran the select query with those values and it worked

Comment: did you set a output clause on the merge.. to see what is inserted / deleted?

(output deleted.UpdateUUID,inserted.UpdateUUID,deleted.UpdateTimeStamp,inserted.UpdateTimeStamp;)

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is the "GO" keyword after the merge process:

```
declare @now AS DATETIME = GETUTCDATE(),
        @uuid AS INT = 1;

MERGE A.V_Table AS T
(
  Select 
     A1,
     A2
  FROM B.Table
)S
on T.A1 = T1.A1
   and T.A2 = T1.A2
when not matched by target then
insert
(
  A1,
  A2,
  UpdateUUID,
  UpdateTimeStamp
)
values
(
 s.a1,
 s.a2,
 @uuid,
@now
); 
GO

select *
from A.V_Table
where updateuUid = @uuid and UpdateTimeStamp = @now;
```